# Count tables in database have more than one record in SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Is there any query which return count of the tables having record more than one row?

Comment: Yeah, the count function.

Comment: SELECT Count(*)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

Comment: It is a query returning me count but I want to count table which are not empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
select
    TableName = sc.name +'.'+ ta.name, RowCnt = sum(pa.rows) 
from 
    sys.tables ta
    join sys.partitions pa on pa.object_id = ta.object_id
    join sys.schemas sc on ta.schema_id = sc.schema_id
where 
    ta.is_ms_shipped = 0 
    AND pa.index_id IN (1,0)
group by sc.name,ta.name
having sum(pa.rows) > 0
```